# Algebraic extension over field $F$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose I am given a field $F$ and two irreducible polynomials $f,g\in F[X]$ where $f\not =g$. Let $a$ be a root of $f$. We then can create an algebraic field extension $F(a)$ of $F$. Is there a situation where $g$ is reducible in $F(a)[X]$? If so, can someone give me an example of such polynomials? If no, how can I prove it?

Comment: If $g$ has a root in $F(a)$ then it is of the form $\sum_{n=0}^{deg(f)-1} c_n a^n, c_n \in F$. But it can have no roots and still be reducible, so it is complicated.

Comment: Finite fields provide lots of examples of this sort since F(a) depends only on the degree of f and g is reducible in F(a) if and only if the degree of g divides the degree of f.

Comment: Asvin's on the right track. But I think in that set up it suffices that the degrees of $f$ and $g$ have a common factor. Then the splitting fields of $f$ and $g$ will share a common intermediate field, and neither is irreducible over that

Comment: But, as indicated by all the commenters and answerers, it often happens that $g$ is reducible in $F(a)[X]$. For example $g(x)=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ becomes reducible over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ gotten with $f(x)=x^2-5$ as
$$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1=(x^2-\phi x+1)(x^2+(1+\phi)x+1)$$ with $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$, the golden ratio.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : That's one sexy example! Better than the usual $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ over the reals...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take $f=g$.

A perhaps less trivial situation is if you think of the minimal polynomial $f$ of $\alpha$ over $F$ and take $\beta \in F$ ; then let $g$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha + \beta$. Since $\alpha \in F(\alpha) \setminus F$, so does $\alpha + \beta$. Therefore $g$ and $f$ are irreducible over $F$ but $g$ is reducible over $F(\alpha)$ since it admits the root $\alpha+\beta \in F(\alpha)$.

Hope that helps,